# How to store variable from a callback to a global class variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop, retrofit

I tried to put a value from a callback function into the class global variable (posterPath)... but when I put it and print the class  variable (posterPath )it outputs 'null'... pls what's the right way to store the value in the class global variable

Class global variable:  `public String posterPath;`

Value:  `posterPath  = result.getResults().get(0).getPosterPath();`

full code:

```
 public void callListOfMoviesApi(Context context) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(credentials.BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MovieApi movieApi = retrofit.create(MovieApi.class);

        Call<PopularMovieModel> call = movieApi.listOfMovies(category, credentials.ApiKey);


        call.enqueue(new Callback<PopularMovieModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PopularMovieModel> call, Response<PopularMovieModel> response) {
                PopularMovieModel result = response.body();

                posterPath  = result.getResults().get(0).getPosterPath();
//        Toast.makeText(context, "response" + posterPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PopularMovieModel> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Update: I researched a lot and found out that my global variable outputs null because the global variable gets called in the Main Thread, and retrofit hasn't assigned a value to the variable yet. (I used Thread.sleep() and the value wasn't null).  But I suspect that is a bad practice. what is the best way to wait to assign a retrofit result to a global variable?

Comment: This would indicate that your server response is giving you null. `result.getResults().get(0).getPosterPath()` - have you confirmed your API response is actually what you think it should be?

Comment: @dominicoder Yes I have confirmed the sever response using Toast and it gives the expected result ..

Comment: Also when I implicitly add values like: posterPath = "hello" ... And then print the posterPath global variable I still get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is mainly because the network request is asynchronous. What you want to do is to return a LiveData from callListOfMoviesApi and in the caller you observe for the result. You can have something like this

```
public LiveData<String> callListOfMoviesApi(Context context) { 

// declare you LiveData<String>
MutableLiveData<String> posterPath = new MutableLiveData<>();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(credentials.BaseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build(); 

MovieApi movieApi = retrofit.create(MovieApi.class); 
Call<PopularMovieModel> call = movieApi.listOfMovies(category, credentials.ApiKey); 

call.enqueue(new Callback<PopularMovieModel>() { 
    @Override public void onResponse(Call<PopularMovieModel> call, Response<PopularMovieModel> response) { 
        PopularMovieModel result = response.body(); 
        if(result != null){ 
           // Add the result to your LiveData 
          posterPath.postValue(result.getResults().get(0).getPosterPath();); 
        } 
        // posterPath = result.getResults().get(0).getPosterPath();
        // Toast.makeText(context, "response"  + posterPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 
    @Override public void onFailure(Call<PopularMovieModel> call, Throwable t) {
         t.printStackTrace();
    }
});

return posterPath;}
```

And in the caller you can observe for the result like this

```
callListOfMoviesApi(context).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), posterPath -> {
                            // use your posterPath
                            if(posterPath != null)
                                Log.i("PosterPath", posterPath);
                        });
```

For more on LiveData see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)